# Can I create a const object from a json string?

Tags: dart

I want to create a const object from a fixed JSON string.
This json string is comming from a --dart-define parameter.

I'm getting it using `const _APP_CONF = String.fromEnvironment('APP_CONF', defaultValue: '{}');`

I've tried the code below, but it is not working. the compiler is complaining about the second constructor:

```
class AuthnProvider {
  final String id;
  final String clientId;
  final List<String> scopes;

  const AuthnProvider(
      {this.id,
      this.clientId,
      this.scopes});

  const AuthnProvider.fromJson(final Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        clientId = json['clientId'],
        scopes = json['scopes'].cast<String>();
```

The json parameter is coming from `json.decode()` method.

I also tried to create const and final var from from the json map and use the first constructor, but compiler gives error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. `const` create a compile-time constant. Dart does not execute code during compilation and therefore cannot create a `const` from a `Map`. This is the reason `const` constructors can't have a body and why there is no other way to work around this limitation.

You don't mention the reason for doing this in your question, but if it's for performance, the difference will be negligible. If it's for immutability, all the fields we see are already `final`, so making the object `const` makes no difference.

Comment: the reason is that I was just trying to create the const object directly from the `String.fromEnvironment()` value, instead of creating a const and then the object. thanks!